# C++ protected access

Tags: c++

is there anyway i can access a protected variable in a class without inheritance.

```
class ClassA{
  protected:
    int varA; 
};

class ClassB{
  protected:
    ClassA objectA;

};


ClassB theMainObject;
```

I would like to access varA through theMainObject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume modifying definition of ClassA is forbidden.

Here is a tricky way for you, but I don’t encouraging you to use it :)

```
class ClassA
{
protected:
   int varA; 
};

class ProtectedRemover // magic thing
{
public: // <- Note this! :)
   int varA;
};

class ClassB
{
protected:
   ClassA objectA;

public: // Just add two methods below

   int getProtectedVarA()
   {
      return reinterpret_cast<ProtectedRemover*>(&objectA)->varA;
   }

   void setProtectedVarA(int i)
   {
      reinterpret_cast<ProtectedRemover*>(&objectA)->varA = i;
   }
};

int main()
{
   ClassB theMainObject;

   // Set protected thing.
   theMainObject.setProtectedVarA(3); 

   // Get protected thing.
   std::cout << theMainObject.getProtectedVarA() << std::endl;
}
```

So there is a way to access and modify protected/private data.
Who was thinking it is impossible, vote up ;)

Comment: -1 This is undefined behavior as those types are unrelated as far as the compiler can see, especially if `ClassA` has virtual methods the OP didn't show us.

Comment: There are no virtual functions in the question men! Why folks here are full of a willing to down vote?
I understand that you have also posted an answer, but still, it is not fair :)
Why you think that author don’t know how to add accessors to ClassA? :) Your answer should be down voted first :)

Comment: + there is no any undefined behavior in my example! :)

Comment: I'd have up-voted your creative answer (and it is) if not for your senseless, just-for-spite down-vote & comment on Mark-B's answer. Too bad amigo, that's not the way to deal with criticism.

Comment: I really appreciate this answer. Thanks for trying to understand my issue.Cheers everyone for helping.

Comment: The only thing you are allowed to do with result of reinterpret_cast is to cast it back to original type. All other uses invoke UB. Anyway, in many compilers it might work.

Comment: @user346443 I’m glad you have liked the answer, thanks for marking it! C++ is beautiful with its tricks ;)

Comment: @Hovhannes this is undefined behaviour. Just because it happens to work doesn't mean thats any less true, it might not work on some compilers or even future versions of the same compiler.

Comment: @Alasdair I can bet nobody can bring an example of such a compiler ;)

Answer (score 5):

You could make `classB` friend of `classA`

```
class ClassA{
  protected:
    int varA; 

  friend ClassB;
}
```

but using a accessors would probably be better since you are not coupling the classes together.

```
class ClassA{
  int getA() { return varA;}
  void setA(int a) { varA = a; }
  protected:
    int varA; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have an accessor function is the only way ie;

```
public:
   int getVarA(){return varA;}
```

Comment: You should make it `int getCarA() const`.

Comment: You're right @Space_C0wb0y, I'm usually just too lazy to mark const functions :p

Answer (score 2):

Add standard getter/setter functions:

```
int ClassA::GetVarA()  
{  
    return varA;
}  
BOOL ClassA::SetVarA(int nNewVar)  
{  
    // Perform verifications on nNewVar... Return FALSE if didn't go well.  

    // We're satisfied. Set varA to the new value.  
    varA = nNewVar;  

    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`friend` is your friend.Use that keyword by mentioning the class in which you want to access as  a friend in the class for which u want to use!

Answer (score 1):

You can't, and quite possibly shouldn't, access `varA` directly from `theMainObject`. `protected` is the same as private for unrelated classes (such as your two example class) so `varA` has no visibility. Use `ClassA`'s normal API to manipulate its state.

If `varA` is part of the result state of `ClassA` and you just need read access to it, then you should add a public accessor to that class:

```
public:
   int getVarA() const
   {
       return varA;
   }
```

Comment: -1 for downvoting my creative answer and because you think author don't know how to add an accessor!!! :)

Comment: I agree.But i'm not going to down vote it as i do appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Besides of making ClassB a friend of ClassA there are some standard and non-standard hacks to get to ClassA internals. You can read [Herb Sutter's article](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/076.htm) about them.

Answer (score 0):

As Mark B mentionned, solution proposed by Hovhannes Grigoryan is not safe and may have unexpected behaviour because ProtectedRemover and classA are unrelated....

I used this in the past, and it may be safer I think:

```
class ClassA
{
protected:
   int varA; 
};

class ProtectedRemover : public ClassA // now, they are related!
{
public: // <- Note this! :)
   int getA() { return varA; }
   void setA( int a ) { varA = a; }
};

class ClassB
{
protected:
   ClassA objectA;

public: // Just add two methods below

   int getProtectedVarA()
   {
      return ((ProtectedRemover)*(&objectA))->getA();
   }

   void setProtectedVarA(int i)
   {
      ((ProtectedRemover)*(&objectA))->setA(i);
   }
};
```

Note it presents no risk at all to get undetermined behaviour....but may be less than original solution where ProtectedRemover and classA were unrelated....and also easier to do if ClassA has tones of attributes!

Still not recommended unless you really have no other choice (can't modify classA by making your class friend or add settre/getter)!

Nothing's really impossible....